# Php insert/update multple row, using array and not a foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I’m wondering if this is possible, I’ve search and haven’t found anything so about to give up.

I’m looking to do the following for example, note i do not want to use a foreach as that converts it into single queries.

```
$a = (1,2,3);
$b = ('john','Rob','Stuffs');
$c = ('doe','roe','soe');

$sql = "update ppl set firstname = $b, lastname = $c where id = $a";
```

The same can be said for an insert.

```
$sql = "insert into ppl (firstname,lastname) value ($b,$c)";
```

The main reason I'm looking to do this is to optimise the db a bit. There are a lot of single queries that (if this method is possible) could be converted into 1 single query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `insert into table values (), (), ()`

Comment: Ok cool can the same be done for update?

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query , it should help u

Comment: do you want array store in db right ?

Comment: @Manish Patel No just want to store those values inside the array in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (count($a) <= 0)
   return; // nothing to do

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES";
while (count($a) > 0)
{
   $id = array_shift($a);
   $fname = array_shift($b);
   $lname = array_shift($c);

   $sql .= sprintf("('%s', '%s', '%s'),", mysql_real_escape_string($id), mysql_real_escape_string($fname), mysql_real_escape_string($lname));
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); //remove last comma

$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=VALUES(fname), lastname=VALUES(lname)";

//run your sql
```

this will allow you to run all of them at once.

Comment: Cheers thanks, just to add to the answer, the update can be done with the comment made by  Siraj Khan under the initial question. He refers us to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query

Answer (score 0):

For update you can do as follows

```
    $a = (1,2,3);
    $b = ('john','Rob','Stuffs');
    $c = ('doe','roe','soe');

    $i=0;
    foreach($b as $fname){
        if( !empty($b[$i]))
        {
            $sql = "update ppl set firstname = '".$b[$i]."', lastname = '".$c[$i]."' where id = $a[$i]";
        }
    $i++;
    }
```

and for insert you can try

```
    $i=0;
    $var = '';
    foreach($b as $fname){
        if( !empty($b[$i]))
        {
            $var .= "(".$a[$i].",'".$c[$i]."','".$b[$i]."') ";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if(!empty($var)){
        $sql = "insert into ppl(id,firstname,lastname) values ".$var;
    }
```

Comment: Ok so there's no way to do an update without a foreach. So they will be single queries each time?

Comment: with update its not possible to do in a single query