# Mysql Bulk Update: Which is the right method?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I found several questions and answers about **Mysql Bulk Update**. And found good solutions from these questions - [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql).

So my table looks like this.

**subscribers**

***firstname*** |
***lastname*** |
***subscriberid*** |
***inactivereason*** |
***statusflag***

Here,

***firstname*** => **VARCHAR** - *not null*

***lastname*** => **VARCHAR** - *not null*

***subscriberid*** => **BIGINT** - *primary key*,*not null*, *unique*

***inactivereason*** = > **VARCHAR** -  *NULL(default)*

***statusflag*** => **ENUM('YES','NO')** - *not null*

And I have used the following query.

```
INSERT INTO subscriber (subscriberid,inactivereason,statusflag) VALUES (1002,"nothing","YES"),(1003,"NO Reason","YES"),(1004,"No valid Data","YES"),(1001,"Poor quality","YES")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inactivereason=VALUES(inactivereason),statusflag=VALUES(statusflag);
```

But I got the following error

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value

But I cannot make any default value for `firstname`. Is it mandatory?

So how can I solve this problem? I cannot take the risk of performance because I have more than 100k subscribers.

Please suggest me the best way.

Comment: because you have set `firstname` as `not null`. alter table schema and allow null values for `firstname`

Comment: @Saurabh, Yes it should be **not null**