# MySQL UPDATE multiple rows with results from API

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, I have a table with 4 columns. The first 2 columns are sourced from a feed. The columns value1 and value2 I need to update using results from API requests. The values from the API request should go into value1 and value2

```
+---------+------+-------+-------+
| prod_id | name | value1| value2|
+---------+------+-------+-------+
|   1105  | aat  |       |       |
|   1108  | bbv  |       |       |
|   1111  | ccq  |       |       |
|   1116  | dde  |       |       | 
|   1123  | iir  |       |       |
|   1125  | jjm  |       |       |
+---------+------+-------+-------+
```

For example the API request gives me these values:

```
1108, banana, apple
1116, cucumber, pineapple
1123, orange, melon
```

So in this example I would like to update these 3 records, but in my case I would have update around 1000-2000 records at a time.

```
+---------+------+--------+----------+
| prod_id | name | value1 | value2   |
+---------+------+--------+----------+
|   1105  | aat  |        |          |
|   1108  | bbv  |banana  |apple     |
|   1111  | ccq  |        |          |
|   1116  | dde  |cucumber|pineapple | 
|   1123  | iir  |orange  |melon     |
|   1125  | jjm  |        |          |
+---------+------+--------+----------+
```

How would I be able to update, say 2000 records using only one or a handful of queries? Would I need to use a temporary table or is there a way to do without?

Comment: I think you are FORCED to use an intermediary language, not directly from MySQL, like PHP, C#, Java, c++ etc. Query the Database->Query the API->Update the Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a kind of batch update using `CASE` as described in [How to bulk update mysql data with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query).

Alternatively if you control the database schema you can insert the results of the API calls in batch `INSERT` statements and then `JOIN` when you need to lookup a particular value.

**Table `A`**

```
+---------+------+
| prod_id | name |
+---------+------+
|   1105  | aat  |
|   1108  | bbv  |
|   1111  | ccq  |
|   1116  | dde  |
|   1123  | iir  |
|   1125  | jjm  |
+---------+------+
```

**Table `B`**

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| prod_id |  value1  |   value2  |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|   1108  | banana   | apple     |
|   1116  | cucumber | pineapple |
|   1123  | orange   | melon     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

When results are retrieved from API calls they can be inserted in batch.

```
INSERT INTO B (prod_id, value1, value2) VALUES 
(1108, 'banana', 'apple'), 
(1116, 'cucumber', 'pineapple'), 
(1123, 'orange', 'melon')
```

Later if you need all values for `prod_id` 1108 for instance you can retrieve them whit a simple join of tables `A` and `B`.

```
SELECT A.prod_id, A.name, B.value1, B.value2
FROM A JOIN B ON A.prod_id = B.prod_id
WHERE A.prod_id = 1108
```

Comment: The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query) you provided was very helpful. For my purposes the easiest solution was the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" one mentioned by user Yaroslav.